# Best way to dynamically enumerate a list of types, and then route tasks based on those types?

Tags: scriptable-object

I am programming a Jobs Queue in Unity, so that I can send Tasks/Jobs to a central queue where the tasks will be processed.

First, I defined 3 possible job types inside of a Scriptable Object.

`public enum jobsType {justPlay, playAndWait, justWait}`

Then I defined a class inside of the same Scriptable Object, so that each Jobs could have 3 inputs: a GameObject, a jobs Type, and a float.  Here's the whole Scriptable Object.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using Unity.VisualScripting;

public enum jobsType {justPlay, playAndWait, justWait}

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New JobsData", menuName = "Jobs Data", order = 51)]

public class JobsData : ScriptableObject {

    [SerializeField]
    public JobsItem thisJobsItem;

    [IncludeInSettings(true)]
    [System.Serializable]
    public class JobsItem {

    [SerializeField]
    public jobsType typeOfJob;

    [SerializeField]
    public GameObject thisGameObject;

    [SerializeField]
    public float jobsNumber;
}
}
```

Then in my code, I use a Switch to route the jobs processing based on the jobs Type enum.  This code is working great - so far, so good!

That said, I don't want to have to modify this JobsData Scriptable Object every time I want to add a new jobs Type.  I'm trying to honor the Open-Closed Principle: "software entities (classes, modules, methods, etc.) should be open for extension, but closed for modification."

It would be ideal if I could define jobsType to be a separate Scriptable Object... and then use a Switch to route between various jobsTypes.

At first, I was considering doing the following:

1. Create Scriptable Object assets using JobsData, where each asset represents a Jobs Type
2. Create a List of these Scriptable Object assets
3. Use that List to dynamically generate an Enum (not sure if this is possible)
4. Then use that Enum to power a Switch. (also don't see how this is possible).

But as I thought it through, I realized that this might not be the best path forward...  since as I understand it, Enums must be specified at compile time.  Beyond that, I can't figure out how I would even use any dynamically-generated Enums in my Switch.

Right now my code works because I define my Enums in the class, but not sure how to achieve the same thing with a dynamic Enum (if those are even possible).

I'd love to be able to define my JobsTypes as Scriptable Object assets, and then route jobs based on those assets.  Given that:

1. Is there an alternative to a Switch I could use to route JobsTypes to the appropriate processing code?
2. Or alternatively, is there a way I could use dynamically-generated Enums in a Switch?

Or maybe I'm thinking about this all wrong?  Open to any and all ideas!

Comment: I think you'll get better answers if you phrase your question in terms of "How can I solve this problem?" rather than "Is it possible to use the solution I already thought of?"

Comment: @DMGregory - I tried to phrase the question more broadly, but struggled to find the right words.  Also, I tried to make it clear that I don't know how to use dynamically-generated Enums in a Switch.

If anyone has ideas on how I can better word the title question, happy to edit!!  It's something I struggled with...

Comment: I don't think a dynamically generated enum is the best solution here. Have you considered a dictionary mapping types or objects to delegates?

Comment: I did consider a dictionary but wasn't sure how to configure it.  Would the idea be to create a dictionary at runtime, and then use strings from the dictionary to power a Switch?

Comment: You don't need a switch. The dictionary can contain delegates that run the code that would have been inside the switch cases.

Comment: That sounds very promising!  I will try to Google it... and if anyone has thoughts or advice on how to do it, I will accept it as an answer!!

Answer (score 2):

As I reread your question, I think you can do this with just plain old inheritance. First we'll declare an abstract base class for all our job types, and expose a `Process()` method. Here I've defined it as an `IEnumerator` on the assumption that you want these to run as coroutines so they can include delays, based on your "wait" names, but you could also make it just a plain `void` method if you don't need that.

```cs
public abstract class JobType : ScriptableObject {
    public abstract IEnumerator Process(JobData data);
}
```

Then we can implement derived classes for each distinct processing behaviour you need:

```cs
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName="JustPlayJobType.asset", menuName="Job Type/Just Play")]
public class JustPlayJobType : JobType {
    public override IEnumerator Process(JobData data) {
        // "Play" code goes here.
        yield break;
    }
}

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName="PlayAndWaitJobType.asset", menuName="Job Type/Play and Wait")]
public class PlayAndWaitJobType : JobType {
    public override IEnumerator Process(JobData data) {   
        // Play" code goes here. 
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(data.jobItem.number);       
    }
}
```

Then instead of a switch statement, you can just read the job type scriptable  object from your job item and invoke its process method:

```cs
IEnumerator ProcessJobs(Queue<JobData> jobs) {
    jobsInProgress = true;
    while (jobs.Count > 0) {
        var job = jobs.Dequeue();
        var jobType = job.jobItem.jobType;
        yield return jobType.Process(job);
    }
    jobsInProgress = false;
}
```

You can then run `ProcessJobs` as a coroutine and it will run the jobs sequentially, including waits as specified by the respective job types in the collection.

Comment: In the past, this route has always been the easiest to work with. Very extendable to new Jobs, and there's a good localization of control. It's very easy to want to treat the jobs as flags for behavior that is defined elsewhere, but logistically it's a lot better to let the jobs define that behavior themselves.